# how to run pytest in nox envionment in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, nox

I am working on a open source repo, and it has nox configured to run unit tests. sometimes i want to debug this unit tests, however not able to figure out how to do that.

I run the nox command as below.

```
nox -R -s unit-3.11 -- -k test_load_table_from_dataframe_w_datatype_mismatch
```

**Output**

```
nox > Running session unit-3.11
nox > Re-using existing virtual environment at .nox/unit-3-11.
nox > py.test --quiet --cov=google/cloud/bigquery --cov=tests/unit --cov-append --cov-config=.coveragerc --cov-report= --cov-fail-under=0 --capture=tee-sys tests/unit -k test_load_table_from_dataframe_w_datatype_mismatch
```

I tried running unit tests using pycharm but then it shows error for missing dependencies.